# how to get data from mongodb collection by match data in subdocument?

Tags: mongodb

i have mongodb collection with data like

```
   var data = [
{
    name: 'test1',
    attributes: [
        {
            name: 'color',
            value: 'red'
        },
        {
            name: 'size',
            value: 'L'
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: 'test2',
    attributes: [
        {
            name: 'color',
            value: 'blue'
        },
        {
            name: 'size',
            value: 'S'
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: 'test3',
    attributes: [
        {
            name: 'color',
            value: 'red'
        },
        {
            name: 'size',
            value: 'S'
        }
    ]
}
```

]

how to query into database so that it will return the documents matching attribute name 'color' having value 'red' and attribute name 'size' having value 'L'?

means it should return

```
 var output = [
{
    name: 'test1',
    attributes: [
        {
            name: 'color',
            value: 'red'
        },
        {
            name: 'size',
            value: 'L'
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Comment: May I ask why you don't have `{name:'test1',color:'red',size:'L'}`? Just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `$and` operator in the `find` query.

```
db.collection.find({$and:[{"attributes.name":"color","attributes.value":"red"}, 
                          {"attributes.name":"size","attributes.value":"L"}]})
```

Comment: The criteria specified here is required to match 2 docs in array, does $and help?

Comment: Yes. `$and` looks for a document which conforms to all its conditions. The first condition is met by the first element in the attributes array, the second by the second element. This document would have been returned even if there was another attribute sub document in the array which failed both these conditions.